# Why is the Model's RequiredIf Data Annotation not working for an HTML Kendo Grid

Tags: data-annotations

The grid has multiple columns with a dependency on one of them.  The delivery type column is one of three value characters (E)mail, (P)ostal, and (C)ampus mail.  If P or C are used the user has to enter an address line 1, city, state and zip; if E only address line 1 is allow and must contain a valid email address.  The "Required" data annotation works fine for address line 1 since it is required for any of the delivery type.  However, the "RequiredIf" data annotation does not cause an error if the delivery type is P or C and there is no city/state/ or zip code present.  Is this because it is a Kendo grid ?  The "RequiredIf" works in other applications within this solution.  the grid looks like this:

```
    <div id="AddresseeDetailList" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary();
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddrId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AgencyId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.SessionId)
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ManageAddressee>()
                    .Name("ManageAddresseeGrid")
                    .Columns(c =>
                    {
                        c.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); command.Edit(); }).Width(180);
                        c.Bound(a => a.Id).Hidden();
                        c.Bound(a => a.Addressee).Width(150).Title("Addressee");
                        c.Bound(a => a.AgencyName).Width(225).Title("Agency Name");
                        c.ForeignKey(ac => ac.AddrTypeCode, Model.AddrTypeList, "Value", "Text").Width(125);
                        c.ForeignKey(ac => ac.DeliveryTypeCode, Model.DeliveryTypeList, "Value",
                             "Text").Width(135);
                        c.Bound(a => a.Addr1).Width(250).Title("Address Line 1").;
                        c.Bound(a => a.Addr2).Width(200).Title("Address Line 2");
                        c.Bound(a => a.CityName).Width(150).Title("City Name");
                        c.Bound(a => a.StprovCode).Width(125).Title("State or Province");
                        c.Bound(a => a.ZipCode).Width(100).Title("Zip Code");
                    })
                    .DataSource(d => d.Ajax()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ManageAddresseeList", "AddressAdmin", 
                                   new { selectedAddressee = Model.Addressee }))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateAddresseeRecord", "AddressAdmin", 
                                   new { sessionId = Model.SessionId }))
                        .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteAddressRecord", "AddressAdmin", 
                                   new { sessionId = Model.SessionId }))
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(a => a.Id);
                            model.Field(f => f.AgencyId).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(f => f.AgencyName).Editable(false);
                        }))
                    .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Enabled(true))
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
                          .ConfirmDelete("Continue to delete this record?")
                          .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Continue to delete this record?"))
                    .Events(e => e.Save("refreshGrid"))
                    .Pageable(p => p.Enabled(true).Refresh(true))
                    .Height(700))
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is part of the model:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An email address or physical address is required.")]
        public string Addr1 { get; set; }
        public string Addr2 { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("DeliveryTypeCode", Operator.NotEqualTo, 'E', 
                     ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.  Please Enter...")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("DeliveryTypeCode", Operator.NotEqualTo, 'E', 
                     ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.  Please Enter...")]
        public string StprovCode { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("DeliveryTypeCode", Operator.NotEqualTo, "E", 
                    ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.  Please Enter...")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Delivery type is a character and I have tried using both "E" and 'E' in the data notation without success.

If this is a limitation using the Kendo Grid, please suggest a solution to this validation need.

Comment: Note this is in a Telerik environment using MS Visual Studio 2019